# How to open multiple FTP servers on different ports on Windows machine?

Tags: windows, ftp

I am currently testing an app that needs to have multiple FTP servers on different ports for a download module.

For example:

- File1.txt must be downloaded on port 21,
- File2.txt must be downloaded on port 22,
- FIle3.txt must be downloaded on port 23, so on..

Is it possible for me to open different ports on a Windows 7 machine?

Is a FileZilla FTP Server an option for me to achieve this?

Comment: what a strange app.  FileZilla is an option.  Make an exception for FileZilla in the windows 7 firewall.    FTP is funny in that it requires 2 ports.. But you may not have to tell the firewall about the ports.. It can just let anything FileZilla through.

Comment: and you have to start multiple filezilla servers. So run filezilla and if you can't see how to start multiple servers in it or start multiple instances of it, however it works, then you could ask a separate question of how to start many filezilla servers.

Answer (score 4):

Windows have an FTP server built-into the IIS.

See my guide on [Installing Secure FTP Server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server).

It shows how to setup a single server only. To setup multiple servers, repeat the [Adding Standalone FTP Site](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#standalone_ftp_site) section for each site you need. Additionally in the *Bindings* settings assign a different port for each site.

[image]

---

The FileZilla FTP server can run a single FTP server only. But you can install it multiple times, into different folders. And configure each instance to use a different port.

---

Though if you need this for testing only, do you really need separate FTP servers? What about having a single FTP server listening on multiple ports, possibly with multiple accounts. The application, you are testing, could not tell a difference.

Both IIS and FileZilla server can listen on multiple ports.

- In IIS, you can add multiple "bindings" to a single FTP site.
- In FileZilla server, you can specify a list of ports in its "Listen on these ports" setting.